# Finite Dimensional Simple Modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

What does mean by finite dimensional simple module?
Generally simple module does not havy any non zero proper submodule.So for that reason I think always simple modules must be 1- dimensional. But this is wrong, I cant find any mistake. Also If M is simple then $ M = m R$ for some $ m \in M $. It implies $ M $ is 1 dimensional. Where am I wrong?

Comment: In general $N$ is not a submodule because for instance there is some $r$ such that $rx_1$ has some $x_n$ in its decomposition.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Often one looks at modules over some finite-dimensional $k$-algebra for a field $k$ and then the dimension refers to the $k$-dimension.

Comment: dimension usually means over a field $k$, so usually this notion comes from representations of a group, which are modules over a $k$-algebra. So these have both, a rank (as modules over a $k$-algebra) and a dimension (considered as a $k$-vectorspace).  are you considering the case of a group representation or a module over an $k$-algebra? I would like to give an example, quite easy one, but depends on the setting.

Comment: forgot to say, the two things:: rank and dimension, not necessarily coincide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One says "finite dimensional module" for a module over an algebra over a field $k$. The dimensionality is that of the $k$ vector space structure of the module.

The dimension of a simple module is quite often not $1$.

For example, if you have a $\mathbb Q$ vector space $V$ of countably infinite dimension, and $R=\mathrm{End}(V_k)$, then $R$ is a $\mathbb Q$ algebra with infinite dimensional simple module $V_R$.

Even when $R$ and $V$ are finite dimensional, the dimension of a simple module does not have to be $1$. For example, $\mathbb C$ is a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb R$ algebra, and a simple module over itself.

As you say, though, a simple module is always finitely generated, in fact always a cyclic module.  The issue is that the minimum number of $R$ generators does not have to match the minimum number of $k$ generators.